# Apache POI initial calculation of formula after download

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I use Apache POI for creating a Excel File. There are two diffrent sheets. 
Sheet 1 is a template with some formulars. In Sheet 2 i want to get the the value of one cell in Sheet 1. This is the Excel-formula to get the value from Sheet 1:

```
=IF(Sheet1!D7="";"";Sheet1!D7)
```

But when I put some text in D7 with

```
  cell = worksheet1.getRow(6).getCell(3);
  cell.setCellValue("SomeText");
```

it wont take over the value to Sheet 2. If i click into D7 and use enter, Sheet2 will take the value, but i want, that apache poi do this.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to evaluate the formula before final output.

Use this in order to evaluate all formulas.

```
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
formulaEvaluator.evaluateAll();
```

Use this in order to evaluate the formula of a specific cell

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
```

And then write the file in the stream